# How can I move a Windows 2003 install to a different logical drive on an HP Smart Array P400?

Tags: windows-server-2003, hp, hardware-raid

I have an HP DL380 with a Smart Array P400 (256MB version). Currently there is a 3 disk raid-5 array that Windows Server 2003 is installed on. I would like to move the (bootable) logical system drive to a separate 2 disk raid-1 array.

Is there a way to do this other than buying the HP 512MB Battery-backed write cache upgrade (405148-B21), and doing a RAID Migration?

UPDATE: Trying to avoid a reinstallation of windows. I'd sooner live with the RAID5, then want to spend the time reconfiguring the server.

Answer (score 1):

yes, two ways:
1. backup, test backup, reinstall, restore
2. ghost/acronis/dd|nc/g4u/etc